# Laravel 5.4 Chunk Upload and Resumable upload for bigger file

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, jqxhr

I want to know if Laravel 5.4 or greater supports chunked file upload for large file size also resumable support in case of network issue.

I have to upload big size videos but due to the network issue, this becomes heck to upload those.

So is there any package or anything.
Currently, I am using ajax file upload.

Comment: did u find a solution?

Comment: Actually didn't implement this right now!!!
I am trying to understand how do I implement this in my current project in which I used xhr request for progress bar.

Comment: Try the solution with package that u have answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, try to use this library: https://packagist.org/packages/pion/laravel-chunk-upload

Installation:

```
composer require pion/laravel-chunk-upload
```

Add service provider:

```
\Pion\Laravel\ChunkUpload\Providers\ChunkUploadServiceProvider::class
```

Comment: Is this upload is Resumable. In case of network connection is lost will this start remaining upload?

Comment: i started the upload , in the middle i refresh the page.When i upload the same file again it starts as new upload.is it possible start the upload from where it was stopped first. i found one demo here https://tus.io/demo.html is it possbile to do same in pio/laravel